# Correct way to change the implementation of a components method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using https://github.com/fmoo/react-typeahead in order to do auto-completion on some text. I want to change it's behaviour so that it will display results immediately (obeying it's maxVisible prop). I'm pretty sure all I have to do is add a few lines of code to the getOptionsForValue method but I am unaware how to extend the component in order to do this.

I heard there might be some hope using ES6 style Javascript so I tried this:

```
class CustomTypeahead extends TypeAhead {
    getOptionsForValue(value, options) {
        var result = [];
        if (value === '') {
            result = options;
        } else {
            result = fuzzy.filter(value, options).map(function(res) {
                return res.string;
            });
        }
        if (this.props.maxVisible) {
            result = result.slice(0, this.props.maxVisible);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

But when that method is called inside TypeAhead (which is defined using React.createClass) my custom method isn't called.